# Why is extras.ubuntu.com down?

Tags: 11.04

I've been trying to update for several days now, and it tells me that extras.ubuntu.com is unavailable. Why is it unavailable?

Answer (score 2):

extras.ubuntu.com is available just fine. You're using an obsolete, no longer supported version of ubuntu for which the extras.ubuntu.com repository was removed the other day. You should upgrate to 12.04 or 12.10

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! I've just removed those repositories from the list so they no longer error. No way am I going to "upgrade" to Unity.